# Compaq Presario CQ71 no power - power LED lights up briefly when plugged in

Tags: hardware-failure, power, compaq-laptop

I have a Compaq Presario CQ71 which will not power on. When plugging in the charger, the LED turns on for about 10 seconds, and then turns off, no other lights turn on. Nothing seems to be happening at all when pressing the power button - the fan doesn't spin and nothing gets displayed on the screen at all.

I've tried holding in the power button for 20 seconds then plugging in power and turning on and still nothing. I've tried removing the HDD, memory, battery, WIFI, disk drive and powering on - still nothing

I've tried a 2nd battery along with 2nd charger. The fact that the power LED lights up when plugged in suggests that the power jack is working OK.

The fan itself is free of dust, and the laptop is only a couple of years old and well looked after. I'm starting to think it's a problem with the motherboard - but would love a 2nd (or 3rd/4th) opinion

What might be causing this issue?

Comment: Troubleshooters here...http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/documentSubCategory?tmp_rule=60018&tmp_task=solveCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&lc=en&product=4143443

Comment: It is also possible the power button board or cable that connects it to the motherboard is bad.

Comment: I've gone through the troubleshooters and checked the connection between power button and motherboard - seems to be secure

Comment: They go bad all the time on certain models, not saying that is your issue, but no real way to check them. What is the full model number of the CQ? CQ71-xxxx-xx

Comment: @Moab CQ71 312SA

Comment: @ kevyn, are you under warranty?, This is a fairly new notebook, so there is not much info from HP about this model (no service manual yet), most likely it will need professional repair, but see this page for some suggestions from HP....http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/documentSubCategory?tmp_rule=60018&tmp_task=solveCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=4036120&query=CQ71%20312SA&tool=

Comment: It's out of warranty (over 1 year old) - thanks for the tip, but sadly nothing provided by HP works

Comment: All that's left for you to do is try another AC adapter, and/or try it without the battery installed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with cq series laptops
the LED next to the power jack is on a return lead from the motherboard, so if it lights then power is getting to the board.
Sadly if it goes out after 5-10 seconds, it indicates that the power distribution part of the motherboard has died. this area is all surface mounted discreet components so repair is very unlikely, a new motherboard is required. it seems to happen when the original battery reaches the end of its life.
Hope this helps.
dougmewpet